# Build VBA Sql statement using 3 multi-select Listboxes and a date range in MS Access 2016 32 bit

Tags: ms-access, parameters, vba

I have three listboxes and a date range on a parameter form. I am able to pass all of the Listbox selections with no problem. I cannot seem to find a way or answer to adding a date range to the where clause.

The Date field is Course_Date, and the textbox control names for the dates are Start_Date and End_Date

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdPreviewReports_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdPreviewReports_Err
    Dim blnQueryExists As Boolean
    Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim qry As ADOX.View
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim strInstructors As String
    Dim strCourseType As String
    Dim strCourseTypeCondition As String
    Dim strRoleType As String
    Dim strRoleTypeCondition As String
    Dim strCourse_Date As Date
    Dim strDateRange As String
    Dim strSql As String
' Check for the existence of the stored query
    blnQueryExists = False
    Set cat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    For Each qry In cat.Views
        If qry.Name = "q_Parameter_Form" Then
            blnQueryExists = True
            Exit For
       End If
    Next qry
' Create the query if it does not already exist
    If blnQueryExists = False Then
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM q_jt_MCR_Instructor_Roles"
        cat.Views.Append "q_Parameter_Form", cmd
    End If
    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
' Turn off screen updating
    DoCmd.Echo False
' Close the query if it is already open
    If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acQuery, "q_Parameter_Form") = acObjStateOpen Then
        DoCmd.Close acQuery, "q_Parameter_Form"
    End If
' Build criteria string for Instructors
    For Each varItem In Me.lst_Instructors.ItemsSelected
        strInstructors = strInstructors & "," & Me.lst_Instructors.ItemData(varItem) & ""
    Next varItem
    If Len(strInstructors) = 0 Then
        strInstructors = "Like '*'"
    Else
        strInstructors = Right(strInstructors, Len(strInstructors) - 1)
        strInstructors = "IN(" & strInstructors & ")"
    End If
' Build criteria string for CourseType
    For Each varItem In Me.lst_Course_Type.ItemsSelected
        strCourseType = strCourseType & "," & Me.lst_Course_Type.ItemData(varItem) & ""
    Next varItem
    If Len(strCourseType) = 0 Then
        strCourseType = "Like '*'"
    Else
        strCourseType = Right(strCourseType, Len(strCourseType) - 1)
        strCourseType = "IN(" & strCourseType & ")"
    End If
    ' Get CourseType condition
    If Me.optAndCourseType.Value = True Then
        strCourseTypeCondition = " AND "
    Else
        strCourseTypeCondition = " OR "
    End If
    ' Build criteria string for RoleType
    For Each varItem In Me.lst_Role.ItemsSelected
        strRoleType = strRoleType & "," & Me.lst_Role.ItemData(varItem) & ""
    Next varItem
    If Len(strRoleType) = 0 Then
        strRoleType = "Like '*'"
    Else
        strRoleType = Right(strRoleType, Len(strRoleType) - 1)
        strRoleType = "IN(" & strRoleType & ")"
    End If
    ' Get RoleType condition
    If Me.optAndRoleType.Value = True Then
        strRoleTypeCondition = " AND "
    Else
        strRoleTypeCondition = " OR "
    End If
    'Build Criteria String for Course_Date
        strDateRange = strSql And " Between Me.[Start_Date] AND Me.[End_Date]"

' Build SQL statement
             strSql = "SELECT q_jt_MCR_Instructor_Roles.* FROM q_jt_MCR_Instructor_Roles " & _
             "WHERE q_jt_MCR_Instructor_Roles.[InstructorID] " & strInstructors & _
             strCourseTypeCondition & "q_jt_MCR_Instructor_Roles.[Course_TypesID] " & strCourseType & _
             strRoleTypeCondition & "q_jt_MCR_Instructor_Roles.[Roles_ID] " & strRoleType & ";"
' Apply the SQL statement to the stored query
    cat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set cmd = cat.Views("q_Parameter_Form").Command
    cmd.CommandText = strSql
    Set cat.Views("q_Parameter_Form").Command = cmd
    Set cat = Nothing
' Open the Query
  If Not IsNull(cboReports) And cboReports <> "" Then
 DoCmd.OpenReport cboReports, acViewPreview  ' use acNormal to print without preview
 Else
 MsgBox ("Please make a Label selection first from the dropdown list to the left.")
 cboReports.SetFocus
 End If
 cboReports = ""

' If required the dialog can be closed at this point
'     DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
 'Restore screen updating
cmdPreviewReports_Exit:
    DoCmd.Echo True
    Exit Sub
cmdPreviewReports_Err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description:" & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume cmdPreviewReports_Exit
End Sub
```

I am also able to provide the database to look at if you wish?

Thank you for helping !!!!!!

William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be:

```
'Build Criteria String for Course_Date.
strDateRange = " And Course_Date Between #" & Format(Me![Start_Date].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format(Me![End_Date].Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
strSql = strSql & strDateRange
```

Comment: You are the only person on the internet who solved this ending days of frustration beyond imagining... I LOVE YOU :)

Comment: Ah, there are a few others as well. But thanks anyway! Then please mark as answered,

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH,Gustav !!! I also added my finished and verified working code for those that wanted to see the whole thing with your help...

Comment: Your edit seems to have been rejected. You can just edit your question to include the essential changes. Don't repeat all of the code.